# Overlay of two images - Control which part is in the foreground with mouse coursor

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I need to be able to compare two different Images in the following way:

The images are displayed on top of each other so first there is only one image visible. When hovering with the mouse coursor over the image this defines the X-position of a vertical line which is splitting the image, displaying part of the first image left to the line and the rest of the second image right to the line.

This basically should be used as a quality comparison for two images with identical contents.

Here is a picture that hopefully makes my intentions clear:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a SplitContainer and custom drawing. As described in the comment of Vasanthakumar's answer purely using a picturebox is not enough as you will not be able to align the right image at the same starting point than the left image (top left of the form).

What I did was the following:

- pictureBox 1 displays its image normally
- the Image in pictureBox 2 is drawn on every move of the splitter (`this.splitContainer1.SplitterMoved += new System.Windows.Forms.SplitterEventHandler(this.splitContainer1_SplitterMoved);` with a custom subset of the Image to be displayed.

This effectively allows to generate the overlay I need.

Part of my implementation showing the drawing logic:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(gImg2.Width, gImg2.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.DrawImage(gImg2, 0, 0, new Rectangle(e.SplitX, 0, gImg2.Width - e.SplitX,   gImg2.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use splitter control. splitter one side you put one picture control another side put other picture control

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to achieve that with the SplitContainer control. However image in the right box has its starting position at the top left of the right container. So basically there is no overlay.